# Recursive function in python does not call itself out

Tags: python, python-2.7

The problem is formulated as follows:

> Write a recursive function that, given a string, checks if the string
>   is formed by two halves equal to each other (i.e. s = s1 + s2, with s1
>   = s2), imposing the constraint that the equality operator == can only be applied to strings of length ≤1. If the length of the string is
>   odd, return an error.

I wrote this code in Python 2.7 that is correct (it gives me the right answer every time) but does not enter that recursive loop at all. So can I omit that call here?

```
def recursiveHalfString(s):
#@param s: string
#@return bool

 if (len(s))%2==0:     #verify if the rest of the division by 2 = 0 (even number)

  if len(s)<=1:        # case in which I can use the == operator
   if s[0]==s[1]:
    return True
   else:
    return False

  if len(s)>1:                           
   if s[0:len(s)/2] != s[len(s)/2:len(s)]:     # here I used != instead of ==
    if s!=0:
     return False
    else:
     return recursiveHalfString(s[0:(len(s)/2)-1]+s[(len(s)/2)+1:len(s)])    # broken call    
   return True

 else:
   return "Error: odd string"
```

---

The expected results are True if the string is like "abbaabba" 
or False when it's like anything else not similat to the pattern ("wordword")

Comment: If `==` is off limits for string length >1, I would assume `!=` is also not allowed. It's essentially `not ==`.

Comment: Using the `!=` operator on strings longer than one character is pretty obviously against the spirit of the task - you could just do `not (x != y)` instead of `x == y` anywhere you want to use `==`.

Comment: `if s!=0:` is always true since `s` is a string. So you can never end up in the else part.

Comment: Also, `s` is a string. It'll never equal `0`. `0` isn't a string.

Comment: Is `'abcabc'` symmetrical by the constraints or do all the nested half strings themselves have to be symmetrical?

Comment: is there combination of strings here ? substirng of main string ? if yes then doing recursive is waste as dividing half string is waste . to check symtery just do str1=str[::-1] . no need to check half only length criteria to be checked

Comment: Your function will never recurse in its current state. Your if condition `s[0:len(s)/2] != s[len(s)/2:len(s)]` will evaluate to false for "abbaabba"  and then the function returns true 5 lines later. For a failing string such as "aabb" that condition will be true, then the following if condition `s != 0` will be true, causing it to return false. You never hit your recursive call.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, the 2 nested half strings have to be identical in order to return True. Therefore the string itself (s) has to be symmetrical

Comment: @MarcusS. So Hmm.. In `abcabc` the half strings are identical, but the string isn't symmetrical. So would that count?

Comment: @KevinWelch, basically the `if s!=0:` command is useless and I've simply solved it without recursion. 
Logically speaking this is a pretty easy task to solve. Why then asking to do it using recursion? 
Maybe it has something to do with the constraint of the == usage

Comment: @schwobaseggl, my bad. Just the half strings identical, then

Comment: Sure this is easy to solve by just evaluating the two halves of the string... the purpose of this problem is to demonstrate an understanding of recursion. The constraints on `==` are so you have to solve it recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another recursive solution. A good rule of thumb when taking a recursive approach is to first think about your *base case*.

```
def recursiveHalfString(s):
    # base case, if string is empty
    if s == '':
        return True

    if (len(s))%2==0:
        if s[0] != s[(len(s)/2)]:
            return False
        else:
            left = s[1:len(s)/2]  # the left half of the string without first char
            right = s[(len(s)/2)+1: len(s)] # the right half without first char
            return recursiveHalfString(left + right)
    else:
        return "Error: odd string"

print(recursiveHalfString('abbaabba'))   # True
print(recursiveHalfString('fail'))       # False
print(recursiveHalfString('oddstring'))  # Error: odd string
```

This function will split the string into two halves, compare the first characters and recursively call itself with the two halves concatenated together without the leading characters.

However like stated in another answer, recursion is not necessarily an efficient solution in this case. This approach creates a lot of new strings and is in no way an optimal way to do this. It is for demonstration purposes only.

Answer (score 6):

This is a much simplified recursive version that actually uses the single char comparison to reduce the problem size:

```
def rhs(s):
    half, rest = divmod(len(s), 2)
    if rest:  # odd length
        raise ValueError  # return 'error'
    if half == 0:  # simplest base case: empty string
        return True
    return s[0] == s[half] and rhs(s[1:half] + s[half+1:])
```

It has to be said though that, algorithmically, this problem does not lend itself well to a recursive approach, given the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Another recursive solution that doesn't involve creating a bunch of new strings might look like:

```
def recursiveHalfString(s, offset=0):
    half, odd = divmod(len(s), 2)
    assert(not odd)
    if not s or offset > half:
        return True
    if s[offset] != s[half + offset]:
        return False
    return recursiveHalfString(s, offset + 1)
```

However, as @schwobaseggl suggested, a recursive approach here is a bit clunkier than a simple iterative approach:

```
def recursiveHalfString(s, offset=0):
    half, odd = divmod(len(s), 2)
    assert(not odd)
    for offset in range(half):
        if s[offset] != s[half + offset]:
            return False
    return True
```